# Parsing through JSON in JSON.NET with unknown property names

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have some JSON Data which looks like this:

```
{
   "response":{
   "_token":"StringValue",
   "code":"OK",
   "user":{
     "userid":"2630944",
     "firstname":"John",
     "lastname":"Doe",
     "reference":"999999999",
     "guid":"StringValue",
     "domainid":"99999",
     "username":"jdoe",
     "email":"jdoe@jdoe.edu",
     "passwordquestion":"",
     "flags":"0",
     "lastlogindate":"2013-02-05T17:54:06.31Z",
     "creationdate":"2011-04-15T14:40:07.22Z",
     "version":"3753",
     "data":{
       "aliasname":{
         "$value":"John Doe"
       },
       "smsaddress":{
         "$value":"5555555555@messaging.sprintpcs.com"
       },
       "blti":{
         "hideemail":"false",
         "hidefullname":"false"
       },
       "notify":{
         "grades":{
            "$value":"0"
          },
          "messages":{
            "$value":"1"
          }
       },
       "beta_component_courseplanexpress_1":{
         "$value":"true"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using C# with JSON.NET to parse through the data.  I've been able to sucessfully get data using this algorithm:

```
User MyUser = new User();
JToken data = JObject.Parse(json);
MyUser.FirstName = (string) data.SelectToken("response.user.firstname");
//The same for all the other properties.
```

The problem is with the `data` field.  This field is based on user preferences mostly and data is only inserted as it is used.  The fields are all custom and developers can put in as many as they want without restrictions.  Essentially, it's all free form data.  Also as you notice they can be nested really far with data.

I've tried to run:

```
MyUser.Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JToken>>((string) data.SelectToken("response.user.data");
```

which doesn't work.

How would you go about converting it to be used in a C# object?

Comment: @KenKin Currently I'm looking at a Dictionary to store the data.  The other member variables are simply string properties which make it really easy to access via MyUser.FirstName.  The question really focus on the `data` portion of the JSON, the rest is purely there for reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can access it via the `JToken` / `JArray` / `JObject` methods. For example, this will list all of the keys under the data:

```
public class StackOverflow_14714085
{
    const string JSON = @"{
                          ""response"": {
                            ""_token"": ""StringValue"",
                            ""code"": ""OK"",
                            ""user"": {
                              ""userid"": ""2630944"",
                              ""firstname"": ""John"",
                              ""lastname"": ""Doe"",
                              ""reference"": ""999999999"",
                              ""guid"": ""StringValue"",
                              ""domainid"": ""99999"",
                              ""username"": ""jdoe"",
                              ""email"": ""jdoe@jdoe.edu"",
                              ""passwordquestion"": """",
                              ""flags"": ""0"",
                              ""lastlogindate"": ""2013-02-05T17:54:06.31Z"",
                              ""creationdate"": ""2011-04-15T14:40:07.22Z"",
                              ""version"": ""3753"",
                              ""data"": {
                                ""aliasname"": {
                                  ""$value"": ""John Doe""
                                },
                                ""smsaddress"": {
                                  ""$value"": ""5555555555@messaging.sprintpcs.com""
                                },
                                ""blti"": {
                                  ""hideemail"": ""false"",
                                  ""hidefullname"": ""false""
                                },
                                ""notify"": {
                                  ""grades"": {
                                    ""$value"": ""0""
                                  },
                                  ""messages"": {
                                    ""$value"": ""1""
                                  }
                                },
                                ""beta_component_courseplanexpress_1"": {
                                  ""$value"": ""true""
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }";

    public static void Test()
    {
        var jo = JObject.Parse(JSON);
        var data = (JObject)jo["response"]["user"]["data"];
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So far this method looks to be the most inline with what I'm trying to do.  I'm going to leave it open for a bit before I accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 18):

Json.NET can actually parse to a dynamic if that is useful to you.
Which means you can do something like.

```
dynamic parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ test: \"text-value\" }");

parsedObject["test"]; // "text-value"
parsedObject.test; // "text-value"
parsedObject.notHere; // null
```

Edit: might be more suitable for you to iterate the values if you don't know what you are looking for though.

```
dynamic parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ test: { inner: \"text-value\" } }");
foreach (dynamic entry in parsedObject)
{
    string name = entry.Name; // "test"
    dynamic value = entry.Value; // { inner: "text-value" }
}
```