# Indexing geospatial in elastic search results in error?

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

```
{ title: 'abcccc',
  price: 3300,
  price_per: 'task',
  location: { lat: -33.8756, lon: 151.204 },
  description: 'asdfasdf' 
 }
```

The above is the JSON that I want to index.  However, when I index it, the error is:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[Failed to parse [location]]; nested: ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [lat]]; ","status":400}
```

If I remove the "location" field, everything works.

How do I index geo? I read the tutorial and I'm still confused how it works.  It should work like this, right...?

Comment: Please add a full description of the steps that you took that resulted in that error.

Comment: Have you tried [other formats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/geo-point-type.html), e.g. `location: '-33.8756,151.204'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error message because the field location s not mapped correctly. It's possible that at some point of time, you tried to index a string in this field and it's now mapped as a string. Elasticsearch cannot automatically detect that a field contains a geo_point. It has to be explicitly specified in mapping. Otherwise, Elasticsearch maps such field as a string, number or object depending on the type of geo_point representation that you used in the first indexed record.  Once field is added to the mapping, its type can no longer be changed. So, in order to fix the situation, you will need to delete the mapping for this type and create it again. Here is an example of specifying mapping for a geo_point field:

```
curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/geo-test/"
echo
# Set proper mapping. Elasticsearch cannot automatically detect that something is a geo_point:
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/geo-test" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_replicas" : 0,
            "number_of_shards": 1
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "location" : {
                    "type" : "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
# Put some test data in Sydney
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/geo-test/doc/1" -d '{ 
    "title": "abcccc",
    "price": 3300,
    "price_per": "task",
    "location": { "lat": -33.8756, "lon": 151.204 },
    "description": "asdfasdf"
 }'
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/geo-test/_refresh"
echo
# Search, and calculate distance to Brisbane 
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/geo-test/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "distance": {
            "script": "doc['\''location'\''].arcDistanceInKm(-27.470,153.021)"
        }
    },
    "fields": ["title", "location"]
}
'
echo
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't specify how you parse it, this:

[Parsing through JSON in JSON.NET with unknown property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714085/parsing-through-json-in-json-net-with-unknown-property-names)

may bring some light in.