# How to parse a JSON array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing

Already checked this post but that did not solve my situation : [Parsing a JSON array using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726197/parsing-json-array-using-json-net)

I have a API response which returns me a JSON array, like the following :

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": "200",
        "description": "OK"
    },
    "response": [{
        "weId": "1",
        "weName": "env1"
    },{
        "weId": "2",
        "weName": "env2"
    },{
        "weId": "3",
        "weName": "env3"
    }]
}
```

**Here's my question :**
This array might return more than 2 values.
What i mean is like this :

```
{
    "response": [{
        "weId": "1",
        "weName": "env1",
        "otherAttribute1": "otherValue1",
        "otherAttribute2": "otherValue2",
        "otherAttribute3": "otherValue3"
    }]
}
```

How am I able to dynamically parse a JSON array, which has an unknown dimension ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you're trying - a simple example of parsing code that doesn't work would really help. I use json.net to parse this kind of stuff all day and it just works.

Comment: Having numbered properties seems like an abuse of JSON. Those should be in an array.

Comment: ...or then those are just examples that it might have any number of properties which names are not known? This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/14714205/1061668

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing through JSON in JSON.NET with unknown property names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714085/parsing-through-json-in-json-net-with-unknown-property-names)

Answer (score 3):

Json.Net can dynamically parse into a `JObject`.

```
var unParsed = @"{
    ""response"": [{
        ""weId"": ""1"",
        ""weName"": ""env1"",
        ""otherAttribute1"": ""otherValue1"",
        ""otherAttribute2"": ""otherValue2"",
        ""otherAttribute3"": ""otherValue3""
    }]
}";

dynamic d = JObject.Parse(unParsed);
Console.WriteLine(d.response[0].weId);
Console.WriteLine(d.response[0].otherAttribute1);

foreach (var r in d.response)
{
    foreach (var prop in r.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }
}
```

Now, that being said, you may not need to do it dynamically. If you have a known set of optional parameters, you can deserialize it into a strongly typed object and anything missing will just be the default value (0 for ints, null for classes, etc), as in the answer below:

```
public static void JsonParsing()
{
    var unParsed = @"{
        ""status"": {
            ""code"": ""200"",
            ""description"": ""OK""
        },
        ""response"": [{
            ""weId"": ""1"",
            ""weName"": ""env1""
        },{
            ""weId"": ""2"",
            ""weName"": ""env2"",
            ""otherAttribute1"": ""value1"",
            ""otherAttribute2"": ""value2"",
            ""otherAttribute3"": ""value3""
        },{
            ""weId"": ""3"",
            ""weName"": ""env3""
        }]
    }";

    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(unParsed);
    Console.WriteLine(parsed.Response[0].OtherAttribute1); // writes a "" since it's null
    Console.WriteLine(parsed.Response[1].OtherAttribute1); // writes "Value1"
    Console.WriteLine(parsed);
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to avoid dynamic unless you have a specific reason to use it.

Comment: He asked how to dynamically parse a JSON. I'm going to trust he has a reason to want to do it dynamically. I don't see why I should be downvoted for answering his question.

Comment: Because using dynamic doesn't appear to be necessary to parse this JSON. You can parse to a strongly typed object. Like I said, dynamic should be avoided unless you have a specific reason to use it. Anyways, assuming that `dynamic` is necessary, this would be a duplicate question.

Comment: @mason If the properties that exist on the object are arbitrary, it is impossible to make a type that can hold the data at compile time, since the shape of the data is unknown at compile time. This is a perfectly valid use of `dynamic`.

Comment: @Asad If the JSON can take any form, then `Console.WriteLine(d.response[0].otherAttribute1);` would result in a crash. However, based on the question, the structure follows a known format and a dictionary would be a much better fit, while avoiding the pitfalls associated with dynamic.

Comment: @mason Well, the `Console.WriteLine` was more of a one time example. But fair enough. I've added dynamic looping over the properties to the example.

Comment: @Pharylon That's better, I've removed my downvote. I still don't think using `dynamic` is a good approach, at least for deserializing that the top level. Perhaps deserializing to a model object that uses a dictionary or dynamic property would be better. But your code is now more robust so I'm satisfied.